# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm using Jenkins 1.579 , SonarQube 4.4 , sonar plugin 2.1. Tried with maven 3.1.1 , 3.2.1 , .3.2.2.

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-     cli) on project at-tracking: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven- plugin:2.0:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-   plugin/2.0/sonar-maven-plugin-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar 
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.4/plexus-utils-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.sonatype.aether.graph.DependencyFilter
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

resolved:

add in jenkins -> plugin manager -> sonar -> advanced -> Version of sonar-maven-plugin -> add 2.4